# Regex to identify the following string

Tags: regex

can anyone help me write a regex to identify the following (including dashes and for varying page numbers consisting either of 1 or 2 alphabetic characters or a string of 1 to 3 numbers).

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - [begin page 90] - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Thanks a lot! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: What have you tried? You can match a character 1 to infinty times using the `+` operator after the character (eg. `-+ \[begin page \d+\] -+`)

Comment: is that amount of dashes fix or varying?

Answer (score 1):

this should do it:

```
^[-\s]+\[begin page (\d{1,3}|\w{1,2})\][-\s]+$


^                  --start of string
[-\s]+             -- first group of dashes
\[begin page       -- begin page literal
(\d{1,3}|\w{1,2})  -- 1 to 3 digits or 2 letters
\]                 -- end of begin page 
[-\s]+             -- trailing group of dashes
$                  -- end of string
```

link: https://regex101.com/r/hqF9hd/1/

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
[- ]*\[begin page ([\d\w]+)\][- ]*
```

See https://regex101.com/r/ftBJ3I/2

- `[- ]*` skip spaces and dashes
- `\[` match `[`
- `([\d\w]+)` match numbers and alphanumbers and capture as group
- `\]` match `]`
- `[- ]*` skip spaces and dashes

Comment: This does not cover 2 alphabetic characters, only digits

Answer (score 0):

for match the first part: `[ -]{36}`
for match the second part: `\[begin page (?:[A-Z]{1,2}|\d{1,3})\]`
for match the third part: `[ -]{36}`

Putting together:

### [`^[- ]{36}\[begin page (?:[A-Z]{1,2}|\d{1,3})\][ -]{36}$`](https://regex101.com/r/hqF9hd/2)

with flags: `g` for global
................  `i` for case-sensitive
................ `m`  for multi-line